# Python. Цикл for. где ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, for

'''Задача «Потерянная карточка»
Условие
Для настольной игры используются карточки с номерами от 1 до N. Одна карточка потерялась.
Найдите ее, зная номера оставшихся карточек.
Дано число N, далее N − 1 номер оставшихся карточек (различные числа от 1 до N).
Программа должна вывести номер потерянной карточки.

есть иное решение в интернете, но я пытался делать по своему. А так не работает'''

```
sum1=0
sum2=0
n = int(input())
for j in range(int(input())):
    sum2 += j
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    sum1 += i
print(sum1-sum2)
```

Comment: Какой лог ошибки?

Comment: Для нахождения суммы от 1 до N есть простая формула, цикл не требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный фрагмент кода верный, то есть вы складываете числа в промежутке от 1 до `n + 1`

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    sum1 += i
```

Но:

```
for j in range(int(input())):
    sum2 += j
```

Данный фрагмент кода неверный. Вам необходимо указать через цикл известные значения.

Например, так:

```
for i in range(n - 1):
    num = int(input()) # вводим известные числа до n - 1
```

Чтобы найти неизвестное число, можно вычитать `sum1` (все числа в промежутке до n включительно) из известных чисел и получить потерянное число:

```
sum1 = 0

n = int(input())

for j in range(1, n + 1):
    sum1 += j # складываем значения итераций от 1 до n включительно

for i in range(n - 1):
    sum1 -= int(input()) # вычитаем из вводимых чисел значения в промежутке n - 1, так как потерянного числа нет
    
print(sum1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю актуален ли данный вопрос. Но я нашел более изящное решение в 1 цикл.

```
n = int(input()) 
sum = 0
for i in range(1, n):
    sum += int(input())
    n += i
print(n - sum)
```

Comment: Если вам интересно, то сумму чисел от 1 до n можно посчитать по формуле  суммы арифметической прогрессии

Comment: `n = int(input()); print((n + 1) * n // 2 - sum(int(input()) for _ in range(n - 1)))` - это изящно.